# ¿Cómo puedo poner un ícono a la derecha de la Action Bar?

Tags: android, kotlin, programación-móvil, actionbar

Quiero añadir un icono que se use para cerrar sesión, pero al incluir el siguiente código el icono se muestra a la izquierda, y a mi me interesa que se muestre a la derecha, este es mi código:

```
// Icono
        supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_cerrar)
        
//listener
        supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        supportActionBar?.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_cerrar)
```

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        return when (item.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                // Maneja la acción del botón en la ActionBar aquí
                // Por ejemplo, para cerrar la actividad, puedes usar:
                //finish()
                cierre()
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIÓN: [Pawan Harariya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16637863/pawan-harariya) me comentó de añadir este código:

`menu_mail.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/cerrar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_cerrar"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="Cierre Sesión"/>
</menu>
```

y

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.cerrar -> {
                cierre()
                return true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
```